# Windows 7 : how to restore the "Security tab" on folders, if "gone missing"

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, windows-registry

For some unknown reason, I had no more "Security" tab when displaying properties of a folder, on my Windows 7 Pro SP1 (with an NTFS-formatted disk).

Thus, I searched the Web, including Super User, but found only this fix supposed to restore it:

- creating `NoSecurityTab DWORD` value under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer`, in the registry; and set it to 0,
- which had absolutely no effect in my case. But that was expected as 0 is the default for this value. So, if the `NoSecurityTab DWORD` value is absent, it is already considered as 0 by the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for quite a while, I ended up to found the solution, though not clearly expressed to solve this very issue. Hence why I created this self-answered "question" to share it with people facing the same issue in the future:

- start the registry with an administrator account, then head to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shellex\PropertySheetHandlers`,
- **check if the following sub-key is present: `{1F2E5C40-9550-11CE-99D2-00AA006E086C}`, if not create it and leave the `(Default)` value as is,**
- switch to Windows Explorer (no need to restart), right-click on any folder to display properties: bang! "Security" tab is back to business!

I didn't check if it works also on other Windows versions (e.g. Windows 10), so if you did, please add a comment to let us know, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have tried other suggested solutions (adding NoSecurityTab in regedit, for example) and I do have the above mentioned sub-key present but still no security tab in my Windows 7 premium. My external hard drive is still locked in read-only mode.
My files are now showing an unchecked Read Only box in Properties however, they are still read only as there is no Delete as an option, for example.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1135789)